# Flextable output to .docx cannot be opened in Word

Tags: r, docx, flextable

I've been trying to import a .csv file into R, then convert it to a flextable, then export the flextable into a Word .docx document. I use the following code

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(readxl)
    library(scales)
    library(janitor)
    library(stringr)
    library(magrittr)
    library(officer)
    library(flextable)
    library(dplyr)
    
    # load data ---------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Rpops_survey <- read_csv("R-POPS Data Quant.csv")
    spec(Rpops_survey)
    
    # convert data ------------------------------------------------------------
    Rpops_survey_dframed <- as.data.frame(Rpops_survey)
    Rpops_ft1 <- flextable(Rpops_survey_dframed)
    Rpops_doctemp <- read_docx()
    Rpops_doctemp <- body_add_flextable(Rpops_doctemp, value = Rpops_ft1)
    
    # export data -------------------------------------------------------------
    fileout <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")
    fileout <- "test.docx" 
    print(Rpops_doctemp, target = fileout)
```

The file is created, but trying to open it in Word produces the following error:
[image: Word docx error]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to make it via R-Markdown.

You should try this next: create a `.Rmd` file and paste in this code:

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  word_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(airquality))
```
Here is the table: `r ft`
````

And knit.

Was an output `.docx` file created without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with how `tempfile` creates the .docx file. The `flextable` [documentation](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/rendering.html#powerpoint-or-word-documents-with-officer) shows to

1. use an empty call to `officer::read_docx` to create an empty .docx file
2. then use `body_add_flextable` to add your `flextable`
3. finally call `print` to save the new document

Here's an example using the `mtcars` data set:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("officer")
library("flextable")

# Do some calculations on an example data set
my_data <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(
    Mean = mean(mpg),
    SD = sd(mpg)
  ) %>%
  rename("Number of cylinders" = cyl)

print(my_data)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   `Number of cylinders`  Mean    SD
#                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1                     4  26.7  4.51
# 2                     6  19.7  1.45
# 3                     8  15.1  2.56

# Create and format the flextable object
my_flextable <- my_data %>%
  flextable() %>%
  colformat_double(j = 2:3, digits = 2) %>%
  add_header_row(values = c("", "Miles per gallon"), colwidths = c(1, 2)) %>%
  vline(j = 1)

# Save output by 
read_docx() %>%                                  # creating a null .docx object
  body_add_flextable(value = my_flextable) %>%   # insert the flextable object
  print(target = "test.docx")                    # print the output
```

That code should produce a Word document with the following table:
[image: Average gas mileage by cylinder]